# mysql select multiple columns of one row from another table

Tags: mysql, select

I usually google my questions, since they are not unique only to me. However, this time I can't find answer (probably not using right keywords).

Problem description:

I have two tables.
First table - **defenition_list** holds unique ID and Name

```
ID | NAME   
-----------
 1 | BMW   
 2 | AUDI  
 3 | VW  
 4 | MAZDA
```

Second Table - **used_id** holds ID from first table

```
ID | def_uid1 | def_uid2 | def_uid3  
------------------------------------
 1 |    2     |     3    |    2    
 2 |    4     |     2    |    1
```

So usually If I need to return value of just one column, I would make select like:

```
SELECT d.NAME, u.def_uid1 FROM defenition_list d, used_id u WHERE d.ID=u.def_uid1
```

But how to write the query to get names of def_uid2 and def_uid3 at same time? So result would look like:

```
ID | def_uid1 | def_uid2 | def_uid3 |
--------------------------------------
 1 |  AUDI    |   VW     |    AUDI  |
 2 |  MAZDA   |   AUDI   |    BMW   |
```

Comment: that depends on what you want, do you want to join the two tables based on the equality of `defenition_list.ID` and any/all of the columns in `used_id` or what?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6973/2 - I assumed u wanted to list into database the top 3 car brand of the user. U could additional User TABLE to be correct & set user_pref  table primary_key (user_id, id_brand). Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. One option is to join your table several times, once for each column you need to grab, or you can write subqueries inside your select clause for each column, like this:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  (SELECT name FROM definition_list WHERE id = u.def_uid1) AS def_uid1,
  (SELECT name FROM definition_list WHERE id = u.def_uid2) AS def_uid2,
  (SELECT name FROM definition_list WHERE id = u.def_uid3) AS def_uid3
FROM used_id u;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91f1a/3) example, using both options that I mentioned.

Comment: @Strawberry what is your alternative?

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to join your names table 3 times:

```
SELECT used_id.ID, d1.name, d2.name, d3.name
FROM used_id
LEFT JOIN definition_list AS d1 ON used_id.def_uid1 = d1.id
LEFT JOIN definition_list AS d2 ON ...
LEFT JOIN definition_list AS d3 ON ...
```